# How to enable rewriteBatchStatements when using gcp cloud sql proxy?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, google-cloud-sql, batch-updates, cloud-sql-proxy

We have a microservice deployed on GKE that connects to mysql db instance on GCP through cloud sql proxy. We are using spring jdbctemplate.batchUpdate to execute batch insert/update statements.
When I append rewriteBatchStatements=true to jdbc url as jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?rewriteBatchStatements=true, it is not able to connect to db instance.

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91)
at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:144)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:956)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826)
... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)

How can I enable rewriteBatchStatements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception was due to missing service entry for cloud proxy in GKE. jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?rewriteBatchStatements=true works fine